# How to order object fields differently?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible when debugging with visual studio to show the fields in an order not alphabetical?

Most times my objects have the usual "name" field but starting with n it ends much much lower in the list(yeah I know I could just call it aaaName) but i don't want to have to do it...

Can't vs just show with the order I put the fields on the code? If not is there a way to move the dispay fields around?

Comment: But if you type `n` you only see properties which start with `n`. Is it still difficult to find it? If you have dozens of properties and fields you might want to refactor your big class into multiple which also increases reusability.

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen any ordering in the debugger, but you can do something even better. With the [DebuggerDisplay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms228992%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-Attribute you can change what the debugger by default displays. You can display the name for example. That's even easier than opening your object and looking for the name.

Comment: yeah this solves the name problem but i still would like the full display to be in my order, i mean in some object i need to watch 30 40% of the fields or so and woudl be much more comfortable if they were at the top